# Defining macro improving syntax of specific function

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I've created a function declared as:

```
template <typename Container, typename Task>
void parallel_for_each(Container &container, Task task,
                       unsigned number_of_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
```

It's not difficult to guess what it is supposed to do. I'd like to create a macro simplifying the syntax of this function and making the its syntax "loop-like". I've come up with an idea:

```
#define in ,
#define pforeach(Z,X,Y) parallel_for_each(X,[](Z)->void{Y;})
```

Where usage as:

```
pforeach(double &element, vec,
    {
     element *= 2;
    });
```

works as expected, but this one:

```
pforeach(double &element in vec,
    {
     element *= 2;
     element /= 2;
    });
```

gives an error

> macro "pforeach" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given

Do you have any idea how to write a macro allowing even "nicer" syntax? Why "in" doesn't stand for comma in my code?

Comment: While it might seem *nicer* on surface, this is obscuring code and making it hard for you (in the future) and others to understand what is really going on. Users will also have to figure out why `pforeach(const pair<int,int>& x, map, { x.second *= 2; });` fails to compile...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas They won't if they understood macros. Also, any user not using type inference in that context...

Comment: @Columbo: If people understood macros the question would not be here :) Also, I don't think there is a simple workaround to handle complex (containing comma) types, as you cannot add an additional set of parenthesis. For those you would have to provide a different macro (or maybe do a single different macro altogether) that requires that the user provides the parenthesis...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that `in` is not replaced is that it appears inside an argument to your function-like macro, but for it to be replaced, those arguments have to be propagated to another macro first: Try

```
#define in ,
#define pforeach_(Z,X,Y) parallel_for_each(X,[](Z)->void{Y;})
#define pforeach(Z,X,Y) pforeach_(Z,X,Y)
```

**Note**: Defining `in` as `,` is not gonna end well!

---

An idea to add "nicer" syntax:

```
template <typename Container>
struct Helper {
    Container&& c;
    template <typename Arg>
    void operator=(Arg&& arg) {
        parallel_for_each(std::forward<Container>(c), std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }
};

#define CONCAT_(a,b) a##b
#define CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT_(a,b)
// Easier with Boost.PP
#define DEC_1 0
#define DEC_2 1
#define DEC_3 2
#define DEC_4 3
#define DEC_5 4
#define DEC_6 5
#define DEC_7 6
#define DEC_8 7
#define DEC(i) CONCAT(DEC_,i)

#define pforeach(Z, ...) \
  Helper<decltype((__VA_ARGS__))> CONCAT(_unused_obj, __COUNTER__){__VA_ARGS__}; \
  CONCAT(_unused_obj, DEC(__COUNTER__))=[](Z)
```

Usable as

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
pforeach(int i, a) {
    std::cout << i << ", ";
};

pforeach(int i, std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}) {
    std::cout << -i << ", ";
};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c61547b11bcb1d50).
Has several disadvantages though. I'd just stick with what you've got so far.

Comment: I have no idea what you've done, but it seems to work perfectly well and the syntax is as good as I would like it to be.Unfortunately right now I don't understand almost any part of your code, but what is most confusing for me - why do you need those DEC_x macros? Does their number limit something? Why there are 8 of them?

PS.: I realize that replacing "in" with comma is controversial at least, I was just playing with it and wondering why it didn't work.

Comment: @Rames Well, the `DEC_x` is necessary to decrement the counter that creates unique values. Boost.PP provides `BOOST_PP_DEC`, which should work with values up to 255, but this one can be extended too. (**It limits the amount of `parallel_for` statements that occur in one single block.**)

Comment: @Rames By the way, the syntax `pforeach(int i, {1, 2, 3}) { /*...*/ };` is possible too, if you extend the code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

> Why "in" doesn't stand for comma in my code?

Because that replacement is performed **after** macro arguments are determined. Quoting standard draft N3797, § 16.3.1 Argument substitution:

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place. ... Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens
>   are available.

So preprocessor identifies `pforeach(double &element in vec, {})` as a function-like macro call with two arguments:

1. First consists of tokens `double`, `&`, `in` and `vec` and bound to argument `Z`
2. Second consists of tokens `{` and `}` and bound to argument `X`

You're obviously miss argument `Y`

> Do you have any idea how to write a macro allowing even "nicer" syntax?

It is hard to answer and it is matter of taste. Anyway, C++ has rich capabilities of patching syntax with operator overload, but you can't build DSL with that, so it is better to use default syntax, it is not that ugly (and also makes it easy to read):

```
 parallel_for_each(vec, [](double& el){ el *= 2; })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no macro langugae. Macros are handled by the C/C++ preprocessor. The implementation of the preprocessors may vary.

Most preprocessors expect that you pass the exact number of parameters. I found that the GNU preprocessor has a less strict checking of parameters what allows a kind of variadic list. But in general a macro won't help you with your task.

I recommend to write the short statement in a function instead of a macro. An inline function is as fast and short as a macro, but type safe.
Further the function allows default parameter values. So you can skip something.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to improve the idea of @Columbo :

```
template <typename Container>
struct __pforeach__helper {
    Container &&c;
    template <typename Arg>
    void operator=(Arg&& arg) {
        parallel_for_each(std::forward<Container>(c), std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }
};

//additional helper function
template <typename Container>
__pforeach__helper<Container> __create__pforeach__helper(Container &&c)
{
    return __pforeach__helper<Container>(__pforeach__helper<Container>{c});
}

#define pforeach(Z,C) \
  __create__pforeach__helper(C)=[](Z)
```

It doesn't rely on `__COUNTER__` and doesn't require defining `DEC_x` macros. Any feedback is most welcome!